# Cannot find control with path error while Initializing Form Array With existing array of multiple objects in angular 13

Tags: angular, typescript, controls, angular-reactive-forms

Hi am new to Angular am looking to initialize form array with existing array consists of multiple objects in angular. am getting following error

> Cannot find control with path: 'variable-> 0 -> id'

**HERE IS MY HTML:**

```
<form [formGroup]="myForm">
  <div formArrayName="box">
    <div *ngFor="let b of getForm(); let i = index">
      <fieldset [formGroupName]="i">
        <legend> <h3>FRUIT DETAILS {{ i + 1 }}:</h3>  </legend>
        <label>Fruit Name: </label>
        <input [formControlName]="name" />
        <label>Fruit Value: </label>
        <input [formControlName]="value" />
      </fieldset>
    </div>
  </div>
  <br />
</form>

<pre>{{ myForm.value | json }}</pre>
```

**AND HERE'S MY TS:**

```
myForm: FormGroup;

  constructor(private fb: FormBuilder) {}

  ngOnInit() {
    this.myForm = this.fb.group({
      box: this.fb.array([]),
    });

    let fruits = {
      data: [{name: 'Apple', value: 10}, {name: 'Orange', value: 5},{name: 'Banana', value: 20}]
    };

    for (let f of fruits.data) {
      const control = <FormArray>this.myForm.get('box');
    control.push(this.fb.group({name: f.name, value: f.value}));

    console.log(f);

    }

    this.myForm.patchValue({ box: fruits.data });
    //console.log(this.myForm.value);
  }

  getForm(): any {
    return this.myForm.get('box')['controls'];
  }
```

Answer (score 0, accepted):

I changed two things to make it work:

In the **TS File** I refactored the `getForm()` method because in my fresh Angular 15 project your code didn't seem to be executable anymore. Therefore you might prevent potential future problems by adapting it as follows:

```
getForm(): any {
    const form = this.myForm.get('box') as FormArray;
    return form['controls'];
}
```

In the **HTML File** I removed the brackets around `formControlName`, since otherwise `name` and `value` would be interpreted as a variable and not as string:

```
<form [formGroup]="myForm">
    <div formArrayName="box">
      <div *ngFor="let b of getForm(); let i = index">
        <fieldset [formGroupName]="i">
          <legend> <h3>FRUIT DETAILS {{ i + 1 }}:</h3>  </legend>
          <label>Fruit Name: </label>
          <input formControlName="name" />
          <label>Fruit Value: </label>
          <input formControlName="value" />
        </fieldset>
      </div>
    </div>
   <br />
</form>
```

Comment: it worked as expected thanks!